# nginx container isn't reachable from outside

Tags: nginx, podman

I have to run a container running nginx as a reverse proxy using podman.

Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx/* /etc/nginx/
```

Where basically I have a default.conf file under conf.d which is like this:

```
server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  my-server;

    client_max_body_size 200M;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED-FOR $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://backend:3300/api;
    }

    error_page  404              /;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

where backend is an alias for another container with a rest server running on the same network that contains the proxy.

I setup the network with the command:

```
podman create custom-network
```

then I run the following command:

```
podman run -d --name=frontend -p 80:80 --network=custom-network:alias=frontend -v ./www:/usr/share/nginx/html -v ./logs:/var/log/nginx localhost/my-www:latest
```

At this point everything is up and running and I can open my application from the browser in the same machine, but it is unreachable from another computer on the same network.

I already turned off windows firewall on every network, but still nothing.

Is there a podman command or a configuration tweak that make nginx container reachable from outside?

Comment: Read this https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/rootless.md. TLDR: using port below 1024 requires root. Try using 8080, if it works, you know where the problem is, couple googles and you should be good to go. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, but if that was the case the cointainer would fail to run right? In my case the container is running fine and i can access everything from localhost. The problem rises when i try from another computer on the same network, no port exposed, no access log in nginx, nothing. It's not just listening on any network other than 127.0.0.1

Comment: I wrote an example of how to run socket-activated nginx proxy with podman https://github.com/eriksjolund/podman-nginx-socket-activation/tree/main/examples/example5 The example uses the systemd directive `User=`, but  that could be skipped to make the example less experimental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same issue on windows and since you mentioned windows firewall I am assuming you are also running it.

I noticed that you did not mention any portmapping.

Get the ip of your podman vm.
`podman machine ssh` and then an `ifconfig`. Then you just map your port like below to your vm ip and your requests from outside should work.

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=<hostport> listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=<containerPORT> connectaddress=172.26.29.96`

Comment: this is exactly what i did to fix the issue. good call

Comment: Hope you didn't waste too much time figuring it out. Maybe mark this as the answer so the next folks can find it faster. :-) 
Now if I can figure this out on a fedora box...